# How to randomize boolean in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this 3k over data that needs to be updated but the problem is that the column type is boolean.
So i tried to randomize the data for "true" or "false" since the column value right now is all "true".
Below is my code:

```
UPDATE dashboard.availability
SET in_opt_hrs = (array['true', 'false'])[(random() * 0 + 1)::int];
```

I have tried using the code above but postgresql throws an error: `column "in_opt_hrs" is of type boolean but expression is of type text`

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just using a boolean expression?

```
update dashboard.availability
    set in_opt_hrs = (random() < 0.5);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4887f88ccc77f2390cf57e1fc41d8e6a) is a db<>fiddle.